# Views - display node referenced by user profile field

Tags: views, users, nodes

Office is content type

User accounts have a **Node reference** to Office, field_office.

I need to create a view which displays `Office->name` where `Office->nid` = `Current_User->field_office`

I can't believe something this simple is so difficult to setup. I've setup another view where `User->field_office` = `Project->field_office`. In that case I created two relationships:

```
Field: Office
(field_office) Content: Office (field_office) - reverse (to User)
```

And a Contextual Filter

```
(field_office) User: Uid
```

Where the default value is current logged in user's uid.

That was easier since both fields are the same (field_office). But I can't figure out how to link a field to a Content nid.

**Update**

It would be simple if I could just create a Contextual filter on Content: nid and set the default value to User: field_office. I can't figure out how to do that though. The only contextual filter option which might support that is PHP code, but what would I tell it to return? This doesn't seem to work (breaks AJAX)

```
$user_data = user_load($user->uid);
return $user_data->field_office['und']['0']['value'];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. Had to create a contextual filter on Content: nid and set the default value to PHP code:

```
$uid = $GLOBALS['user']->uid;
$user_data = user_load($uid);
return $user_data->field_office['und'][0]['nid'];
```

Really weird that this isn't easier to do.